# MYSQL Date of monday in given week and year, mode 7

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the date of the first Monday by given week number and year.

I found this code: `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('20131',' Monday'), '%x%v %W') as MQK;`

It works in most cases, following `mode 3`, but I want it in `mode 7`. [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

For example, if the year is 2013 and week 1, it gives:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('20131',' Monday'), '%x%v %W') as first_day;
+------------+
| first_day  |
+------------+
| 2012-12-31 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm expecting date `2013-01-07`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to specifically find first monday of a year ? Or, it can be used in some other general fashion also ?

Comment: What's 'first' monday?

Comment: @Strawberry first date in a **year** which is Monday. for eg: in 2013, 1 Jan is Tuesday, and first monday comes at 7 Jan 2013

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It's best if the OP can answer.

Comment: @Strawberry OP already answered.  MySQL `WEEK()` mode 7 is well-defined on the page OP linked to: mode 7, first day of week = Monday, weeks numbered 1-53, with a Monday in this year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to implement a conditional to emulate the mode 7 behavior.

```
SELECT @y := 2013 as `@y`, @w := 1 as `@w`,
       @d := STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@y, @w, ' Monday'), '%x%v %W') as `@d`,
       IF (YEAR(@d) < @y, DATE_ADD(@d, INTERVAL 1 WEEK), @d) as first_day;
```

You would get:

```
+------+----+------------+------------+
| @y   | @w | @d         | first_day  |
+------+----+------------+------------+
| 2013 |  1 | 2012-12-31 | 2013-01-07 |
+------+----+------------+------------+
```

And, in 2007 where Jan 1 is the first Monday of the year:

```
SELECT @y := 2007 as `@y`, @w := 1 as `@w`,
       @d := STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@y, @w, ' Monday'), '%x%v %W') as `@d`,
       IF (YEAR(@d) < @y, DATE_ADD(@d, INTERVAL 1 WEEK), @d) as first_day;

+------+----+------------+------------+
| @y   | @w | @d         | first_day  |
+------+----+------------+------------+
| 2007 |  1 | 2007-01-01 | 2007-01-01 |
+------+----+------------+------------+
```

**Added 2018-10-25:**

So, apparently this doesn't work for 2013 week 2, which using the above query results in `2013-01-07` which is actually the Monday for week 1.  In hindsight, this was kind of obvious based on the approach I originally proposed and the obvious solution just jumped out at me.

```
SELECT @y := 2013 as `@y`, @w := 1 as `@w`,
       @d := STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@y, @w, ' Monday'), '%x%v %W') as `@d`,
       IF (WEEK(@d, 7) <> @w, DATE_ADD(@d, INTERVAL 1 WEEK), @d) as first_day;

+------+----+------------+------------+
| @y   | @w | @d         | first_day  |
+------+----+------------+------------+
| 2013 |  1 | 2012-12-31 | 2013-01-07 |
+------+----+------------+------------+

SELECT @y := 2013 as `@y`, @w := 2 as `@w`,
       @d := STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@y, @w, ' Monday'), '%x%v %W') as `@d`,
       IF (WEEK(@d, 7) <> @w, DATE_ADD(@d, INTERVAL 1 WEEK), @d) as first_day;

+------+----+------------+------------+
| @y   | @w | @d         | first_day  |
+------+----+------------+------------+
| 2013 |  2 | 2013-01-07 | 2013-01-14 |
+------+----+------------+------------+
```

Heh.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, I found a bug. `2013 week 1` is same as `2013 week 2` :-(

Comment: @Generalbet - that's interesting - let me take a look.

Comment: @Generalbet - lol, yeah, that was kinda funny - just edited my answer with the more obviously correct solution.  hah.